# Accessing the nodejs public folder from remote window application

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, remote-desktop

I am able to access the html but unable to access the public folder for the application server in a remote windows desktop. It was stored in the D drive of a remote windows desktop. Nginx was in linux instance.

I have tried to use "/mnt/d/pathtoHtmlFolder/index.html" and "mnt/d/pathtoPublic/public" but it still shows the error in error log. I have already assigned permission to the public folder and subfolder. The items are also within the file path correctly. How to fix?